# C# Regex expression that will capture selection between multiple sets of characters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to be able to capture everything between sets of `##`. For example the strings:

- `##First## the dog ate, ##second## the dog ran` => `['First', 'second']`
- `The dog ##ran##` => `['ran']`
- `##The## dog ran away from ##home##` => `['The', 'home']`

I tried `(?<=##).+?(?=#)` but it captures the first string.

I am using C#

Comment: Why *must* you use a Regex to capture this? And how do you represent the sequence of characters “##” inside your sets?

Comment: What language are you using to process these captured values? Running this through Regex101 clearly shows that both values are captured ([here](https://regex101.com/r/CWYAfk/1))

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I updated the description and title - but I am using C#

Comment: Does something like [`##[\w]*##`](https://regex101.com/r/2lBSSw/1) do the trick?

Comment: @DourHighArch I thought it would be easier than having to loop over the string and process all groups (though it isn't too hard)

Comment: @JamesWhiteley that could work. I can just take the substring in b/w. Thanks!

Edit: Actually `(?<=##)[\w]*(?=#)` does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the look behind and look ahead you are going to capture the string in-between `first` and `second` in `##First## the dog ate, ##second## the dog ran`

To correct that, you need to consume them:

```
(?:##)(?<text>.+?)(?:##)
```

Then when you match, you can use the group `text` to extract the part you want.

For example:

```
var str = "##First## the dog ate, ##second## the dog ran";
var reg = new Regex("(?:##)(?<text>.+?)(?:##)");

var result = reg.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["text"].Value);
```

`result` will contain `First` and `second`

Comment: Alternatively, switch `.` to `[^#]` to avoid capturing delimiters.  Total regex would be `(?:##)(?<text>[^#]+)(?:##)`.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm not capturing the delimiters. Your suggestion is functionally the same.